# Does 4sq allow cloning the checkin feature for third party social networks?

Tags: foursquare, policy, checkin

Out of curiosity and because I couldn't find any information on this in the API policies: Does foursquare allow using the venue database to rebuild the check in feature with another social network?

Say someone builds `MyCoolSocialNetwork` and wants to provide a check in feature that does not  require his users to sign up for foursquare user accounts. Would it be OK to build an app where users would check in at venues taken from the foursquare venue database, but using their `MyCoolSocialNetwork` account? Obviously those `MyCoolSocialNetwork` check ins would only be visible inside `MyCoolSocialNetwork`, but not on foursquare (and vice versa). Technically, `MyCoolSocialNetwork` would have a check in database of its own that would be independent of foursquare's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically this doesn't seem like a violation of the API terms, but I would strongly discourage this for these reasons:

1. You will need to attribute Foursquare in any search results or link to our venue pages when you're using Foursquare data (which you will be). This creates a strong link between Foursquare and your app & the venues you're using.
2. It will then be extremely confusing from a UX standpoint if you're offering your users to check in, but these check-ins aren't reflected on Foursquare itself.

I think you're better off [authenticating](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth) your users through Foursquare and letting them check in on Foursquare itself—all the hard work is already done for you! We also recently released native auth libraries for [iOS](https://github.com/foursquare/foursquare-ios-oauth) and [Android](https://github.com/foursquare/foursquare-android-oauth) to make this process easier.